# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/application.properties]

Tags: java, swagger, spring-boot-test

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.gaian.adwize.ssp.main.SSPStarter]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/application.properties] at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:187) at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:324) at

---

```
Test class
----------
package com.gaian.adwize.swagger;

import com.gaian.adwize.ssp.main.SSPStarter;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.AutoConfigureRestDocs;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

import static org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.MockMvcRestDocumentation.document;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.operation.preprocess.Preprocessors.preprocessResponse;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.operation.preprocess.Preprocessors.prettyPrint;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureRestDocs(outputDir = "build/asciidoc/snippets")
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SSPStarter.class, SwaggerConfig.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class Swagger2MarkupTest {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Swagger2MarkupTest.class);


    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Test
    public void createSpringfoxSwaggerJson() throws Exception {
        //String designFirstSwaggerLocation = Swagger2MarkupTest.class.getResource("/swagger.yaml").getPath();

        String outputDir = System.getProperty("io.springfox.staticdocs.outputDir");
        MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/v2/api-docs")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();

        MockHttpServletResponse response = mvcResult.getResponse();
        String swaggerJson = response.getContentAsString();
        Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(outputDir));
        try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(outputDir, "swagger.json"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)){
            writer.write(swaggerJson);
        }
    }


}
```

Failed to load Application Context and could not be able to load properties file which is in classpath
 Anyone please help me??